# Update Expiration Time in Mongoose Model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm writing a Node.js, Express app and have a mongoose model defined as such:

```
const TeamMemberAttendance = mongoose.Schema({
        date: {type: Date, expires: '44640m', default: Date.now},
        // More lines of code
```

My goal is to update the "expires" property on a request. For example, right now the expiration is set to "4460 minutes" i.e. 1 month. How would I update the Model so that documents expire at some later date?